# Python: using polygons to create a mask on a given 2d grid

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, cartopy, python-iris

I have some **polygons** (Canadian provinces), read in with `GeoPandas`, and want to use these to create a mask to apply to gridded data on a 2-d latitude-longitude grid (read from a *netcdf* file using `iris`). An end goal would be to *only have data for a given province remaining, with the rest of the data masked out*. So the mask would be 1's for grid boxes within the province, and 0's or NaN's for grid boxes outside the province.

---

The polygons can be obtained from the shapefile here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5elu01fetwnobx/CAN_adm1.shp?dl=0

The netcdf file I am using can be downloaded here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxb2v2rq17m7lp7/t2m.20090815.nc?dl=0

---

I imagine there are two approaches here but I am struggling with both:

1) Use the polygon to create a mask on the latitude-longitude grid so that this can be applied to lots of datafiles outside of python (preferred)

2) Use the polygon to mask the data that have been read in and extract only the data inside the province of interest, to work with interactively.

My code so far:

```
import iris
import geopandas as gpd

#read the shapefile and extract the polygon for a single province
#(province names stored as variable 'NAME_1')
Canada=gpd.read_file('CAN_adm1.shp')
BritishColumbia=Canada[Canada['NAME_1'] == 'British Columbia']

#get the latitude-longitude grid from netcdf file
cubelist=iris.load('t2m.20090815.nc')
cube=cubelist[0]
lats=cube.coord('latitude').points
lons=cube.coord('longitude').points

#create 2d grid from lats and lons (may not be necessary?)
[lon2d,lat2d]=np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

#HELP!
```

Thanks very much for any help or advice.

---

UPDATE: Following the great solution from @DPeterK below, my original data can be masked, giving the following:

[image: temperature data from netcdf file masked using shapefile of Canadian provinces]

Comment: You might also be interested in https://gist.github.com/pelson/9785576 which demonstrates the masking using shapely.vectorized. It should be quite performant. If this turns out to be your solution, please do consider adding another answer to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you have started well! Geometries loaded from shapefiles expose various geospatial comparison methods, and in this case you need the `contains` method. You can use this to test each point in your cube's horizontal grid for being contained within your British Columbia geometry. (Note that this is *not* a fast operation!) You can use this comparison to build up a 2D mask array, which could be applied to your cube's data or used in other ways.

I've written a Python function to do the above – it takes a cube and a geometry and produces a mask for the (specified) horizontal coordinates of the cube, and applies the mask to the cube's data. The function is below:

```
def geom_to_masked_cube(cube, geometry, x_coord, y_coord,
                        mask_excludes=False):
    """
    Convert a shapefile geometry into a mask for a cube's data.

    Args:

    * cube:
        The cube to mask.
    * geometry:
        A geometry from a shapefile to define a mask.
    * x_coord: (str or coord)
        A reference to a coord describing the cube's x-axis.
    * y_coord: (str or coord)
        A reference to a coord describing the cube's y-axis.

    Kwargs:

    * mask_excludes: (bool, default False)
        If False, the mask will exclude the area of the geometry from the
        cube's data. If True, the mask will include *only* the area of the
        geometry in the cube's data.

    .. note::
        This function does *not* preserve lazy cube data.

    """
    # Get horizontal coords for masking purposes.
    lats = cube.coord(y_coord).points
    lons = cube.coord(x_coord).points
    lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

    # Reshape to 1D for easier iteration.
    lon2 = lon2d.reshape(-1)
    lat2 = lat2d.reshape(-1)

    mask = []
    # Iterate through all horizontal points in cube, and
    # check for containment within the specified geometry.
    for lat, lon in zip(lat2, lon2):
        this_point = gpd.geoseries.Point(lon, lat)
        res = geometry.contains(this_point)
        mask.append(res.values[0])

    mask = np.array(mask).reshape(lon2d.shape)
    if mask_excludes:
        # Invert the mask if we want to include the geometry's area.
        mask = ~mask
    # Make sure the mask is the same shape as the cube.
    dim_map = (cube.coord_dims(y_coord)[0],
               cube.coord_dims(x_coord)[0])
    cube_mask = iris.util.broadcast_to_shape(mask, cube.shape, dim_map)

    # Apply the mask to the cube's data.
    data = cube.data
    masked_data = np.ma.masked_array(data, cube_mask)
    cube.data = masked_data
    return cube
```

If you just need the 2D mask you could return that before the above function applies it to the cube.

To use this function in your original code, add the following at the end of your code:

```
geometry = BritishColumbia.geometry
masked_cube = geom_to_masked_cube(cube, geometry,
                                  'longitude', 'latitude',
                                  mask_excludes=True)
```

If this doesn't mask anything it might well mean that your cube and geometry are defined on different extents. That is, your cube's longitude coordinate runs from 0°–360°, and if the geometry's longitude values run from -180°–180°, then the containment test will never return `True`. You can fix this by changing the extents of your cube with the following:

```
cube = cube.intersection(longitude=(-180, 180))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks very much for such an elegant and well explained solution, @DPeterK. This works a treat. I eventually managed to hack together a solution using `matplotlib.path` (`path=mpltPath.Path(mypolygon) \ inside=path.contains_points(points)`), but your approach is at least 4 times faster, because it doesn't require breaking _MultiPolygon_ objects into individual polygons first (in this example, British Columbia is a MultiPolygon consisting of >2000 individual polygons!)

Comment: OK it actually turns out I made a mistake with a loop in my method (!) and the approach is a bit quicker, but far less readable and much more difficult to follow than yours (although I guess it could be cleaned up a little by someone with greater knowhow than me). I'm not sure of the etiquette here, so I am going to post it as an answer below yours, but with your answer accepted as the neater solution - and to thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 5):

I found an alternative solution to the excellent one posted by @DPeterK above, which yields the same result. It uses `matplotlib.path` to test if points are contained within the *exterior coordinates* described by the *geometries* loaded from a shape file. **I am posting this because this method is ~10 times faster than that given by @DPeterK (2:23 minutes vs 25:56 minutes).** I'm not sure what is preferable: an elegant solution, or a speedy, brute force solution. Perhaps one can have both?!

One complication with this method is that some geometries are *MultiPolygons* - i.e. the shape consists of several smaller polygons (in this case, the province of British Columbia includes islands off of the west coast, which can't be described by the coordinates of the mainland British Columbia *Polygon*). The MultiPolygon has no exterior coordinates but the individual polygons do, so these each need to be treated individually. I found that the neatest solution to this was to use a function copied from GitHub (https://gist.github.com/mhweber/cf36bb4e09df9deee5eb54dc6be74d26), which 'explodes' MultiPolygons into a list of individual polygons that can then be treated separately.

The working code is outlined below, with my documentation. Apologies that it is not the most elegant code - I am relatively new to Python and I'm sure there are lots of unnecessary loops/neater ways to do things!

```
import numpy as np
import iris
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.path as mpltPath
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon


#-----


#FIRST, read in the target data and latitude-longitude grid from netcdf file
cubelist=iris.load('t2m.20090815.minus180_180.nc')
cube=cubelist[0]
lats=cube.coord('latitude').points
lons=cube.coord('longitude').points

#create 2d grid from lats and lons
[lon2d,lat2d]=np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

#create a list of coordinates of all points within grid
points=[]

for latit in range(0,241):
    for lonit in range(0,480):
        point=(lon2d[latit,lonit],lat2d[latit,lonit])
        points.append(point)

#turn into np array for later
points=np.array(points)

#get the cube data - useful for later
fld=np.squeeze(cube.data)

#create a mask array of zeros, same shape as fld, to be modified by
#the code below
mask=np.zeros_like(fld)


#NOW, read the shapefile and extract the polygon for a single province
#(province names stored as variable 'NAME_1')
Canada=gpd.read_file('/Users/ianashpole/Computing/getting_province_outlines/CAN_adm_shp/CAN_adm1.shp')
BritishColumbia=Canada[Canada['NAME_1'] == 'British Columbia']


#BritishColumbia.geometry.type reveals this to be a 'MultiPolygon'
#i.e. several (in this case, thousands...) if individual polygons.
#I ultimately want to get the exterior coordinates of the BritishColumbia
#polygon, but a MultiPolygon is a list of polygons and therefore has no
#exterior coordinates. There are probably many ways to progress from here,
#but the method I have stumbled upon is to 'explode' the multipolygon into
#it's individual polygons and treat each individually. The function below
#to 'explode' the MultiPolygon was found here:
#https://gist.github.com/mhweber/cf36bb4e09df9deee5eb54dc6be74d26


#---define function to explode MultiPolygons

def explode_polygon(indata):
    indf = indata
    outdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=indf.columns)
    for idx, row in indf.iterrows():
        if type(row.geometry) == Polygon:
            #note: now redundant, but function originally worked on
            #a shapefile which could have combinations of individual polygons
            #and MultiPolygons
            outdf = outdf.append(row,ignore_index=True)
        if type(row.geometry) == MultiPolygon:
            multdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=indf.columns)
            recs = len(row.geometry)
            multdf = multdf.append([row]*recs,ignore_index=True)
            for geom in range(recs):
                multdf.loc[geom,'geometry'] = row.geometry[geom]
            outdf = outdf.append(multdf,ignore_index=True)
    return outdf

#-------


#Explode the BritishColumbia MultiPolygon into its constituents
EBritishColumbia=explode_polygon(BritishColumbia)


#Loop over each individual polygon and get external coordinates
for index,row in EBritishColumbia.iterrows():

    print 'working on polygon', index
    mypolygon=[]
    for pt in list(row['geometry'].exterior.coords):
        print index,', ',pt
        mypolygon.append(pt)


    #See if any of the original grid points read from the netcdf file earlier
    #lie within the exterior coordinates of this polygon
    #pth.contains_points returns a boolean array (true/false), in the
    #shape of 'points'
    path=mpltPath.Path(mypolygon)
    inside=path.contains_points(points)


    #find the results in the array that were inside the polygon ('True')
    #and set them to missing. First, must reshape the result of the search
    #('points') so that it matches the mask & original data
    #reshape the result to the main grid array
    inside=np.array(inside).reshape(lon2d.shape)
    i=np.where(inside == True)
    mask[i]=1


print 'fininshed checking for points inside all polygons'


#mask now contains 0's for points that are not within British Columbia, and
#1's for points that are. FINALLY, use this to mask the original data
#(stored as 'fld')
i=np.where(mask == 0)
fld[i]=np.nan

#Done.
```